# Seleccionar mas de una columna como null

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta en SQL SERVER:

```
Select Column1, Column2, Column3 
FROM DBO.DATA
```

como resultado lo siguiente:

```
COLUMN1  COLUMN2    COLUMN3
A          Q          P
B          NULL       O
NULL       R          L
C          T          G
```

Quiero obtener todos los registros que en alguna de sus columnas tienen nulo y en otra consulta quiero obtener los registros que en ninguna de las columnas tienen nulo

Comment: `Quiero obtener todos los registros que son nullos y los que no son nullos en niguna columna`, qué significa esto?. Por favor muestra claramente el resultado deseado.

Comment: ¿Que significa en ninguna columna?

Comment: quiero obtener los registros que en alguna de las 3 columnas tienen nulo y en un segundo select los registro que no tienen en ninguna columa nulo

Comment: @DEVJ En ese caso, la respuesta de abajo te sirve. Te recomiendo que la próxima vez, si necesitas dos consultas diferentes, lo dejes claro en la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es una especie de "indicador" de nulos, la respuesta sería algo así:

Indicar cuáles tienen nulo en alguna de sus columnas

```
select (case when column1 is null 
             then 'column1 is null'
             else (case when column2 is null 
                       then 'column2 is null'
                       else 'column3 is null'
                  end) 
       end ) cual_es_nula  
  from dbo.data 
where column1 is null or column2 is null or column3 is null;
```

Creo que el otro caso se puede sacar a partir de este fácilmente.

Answer (score 0):

Los que no son nulos en ninguna columna:

```
 SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
 FROM DBO.DATA
 WHERE Column1 IS NOT NULL AND Column2 IS NOT NULL AND Column3 IS NOT NULL
```

Para obtener los que tienen algún valor NULL no tienes más que utilizar el operador IS NULL

```
 SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
 FROM DBO.DATA
 WHERE Column1 IS NULL OR Column2 IS NULL OR Column3 IS NULL
```

Comment: si pero estas usando el AND yo necesito que si alguna de sus columnas tiene nulo me muestre cual registro es

Comment: He ampliado el ejemplo para mostrarte cómo obtener los registros que tienen algún valor nulo. La primera consulta devuelve todos los registros que tienen todos los campos con un valor no nulo. La segunda consulta devuelve todos los registros en los que alguno de los campos tiene un valor nulo.